# Python function that rotates files per call

Tags: python, oauth

I'm using OAuth for a project and have three sets of keys for access in seperate csv files.  Is there a way to write a function that will access one of the three files (in sequence, 1, 2, 3, repeat) every time the function is called?  The only way I can think of doing this "without global variables" is to have some sort of variable in my main function that will keep track.  However, I haven't been able to hack / google-fu my way around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use iter creating the iterator of file names at the start of your code:

```
names = iter([1,2,3])
print(next(names))
print(next(names))
print(next(names))
1
2
3
```

Or itertools.cycle:

```
from itertools import cycle
names = cycle([1,2,3])
print(next(names))
print(next(names))
print(next(names))
print(next(names))
print(next(names))
print(next(names))
1
2
3
1
2
3
```

In your function simply use  `with open next(names) as f:....` where `names` contains the filenames/paths.

Answer (score 0):

With a generator:

```
def accessInSequence():
    while True:
        accessFileOne()
        yield
        accessFileTwo()
        yield
        accessFileThree()
        yield

mySequence = accessInSequence()
mySequence() #file 1
mySequence() #file 2
# ...
```